# Successive calls PresentViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to add a registration page & a verification page to my app that has a 3 views that can be switched to and from using a UITabBarController. The registration page should only be shown once in this app's life time. Once a user is registered, this view will go away and be replaced by a verification page. Once a users identity is verified, a user can use the app.

Now in AppDelegate I have the following code to present the registration page to the user:

```
        RegistrationPage *registration  = [[RegistrationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationPage" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.rootViewController  presentViewController:registration animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After the user filled the registration page and pressed the submit button, the following code is used to dismiss the registration page and present the verification page:

```
    VerificationPage *verification  = [[VerificationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerificationPage" bundle:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self addVerificationPage];
}];


-(void) addVerificationPage
{
 VerificationPage *verification  = [[VerificationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerificationPage" bundle:nil];

 [self presentViewController:verification animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

However the verification page just never shows up. Can someone help me with this?

I have also tried this in the registration page, does not work either:

```
    VerificationPage *verification  = [[VerificationPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerificationPage" bundle:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:verification animated:YES]
}];
```

Comment: Which class is the addVerificationPage method in? If it's still AppDelegate, shouldn't it should be calling presentViewController on self.window.rootViewController (the same as when you present the RegistrationPage), or at least, not on self?

Comment: addVerificationPage is in the registration page. Actually it is getting called, but it never shows up.

Comment: I think it's caused by using a dismissed controller to present another one - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely is an issue caused by attempting to present the `VerificationPage` at the same time as you dismiss the `RegistrationPage`. From the Apple documentation:

> Dismissing a view controller dismisses not only that view controller but also any view controllers it presented.

As a result, there's two possible orders, either of which will result in failure - either the `VerificationPage` is created and presented, then the `RegistrationPage` is dismissed - taking the presented `VerificationPage` with it. Alternatively, the `RegistrationPage` is dismissed and destroyed, then the `presentViewController` call is sent through to it - resulting in failure as the `RegistrationPage` is no longer a valid `ViewController`.

To resolve, either leave the `RegistrationPage` open and present the `VerificationPage` over it (not ideal, but it will work), or signal the `AppDelegate` or a `ViewController` higher up the chain (you can use `self.presentingViewController`) to do the presenting instead.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but how do I get access to the rootViewController from the registration page? If I call self.presentingViewController, which UIViewController actually gets evoked?

Comment: I have also tried: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:verification animated:YES]
}];  It does not seem to work?

Comment: `self.presentingViewController` returns whichever viewController originally called `presentViewController` to present `self` - in your case, from this line `[self.window.rootViewController  presentViewController:registration animated:YES completion:nil];`. You can access your AppDelegate through `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and access your root view controller from there the same as you do for your `RegistrationPage`. The question I have is, have you actually set a root view controller?

Comment: Yeah the root view controller is the tab bar controller. I have tried to move addVerificationPage to AppDelegate.m, then call [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] addVerificationPage] in the registration page, but got this error: "'Not known instance method for selector 'addVerificationPage'". I am sure I declared it in AppDelegate.h.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It just needs some type casting like this: [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] addVerificationPage]

Comment: I had this same problem ... using changing self presentViewController to self.presentingViewController presentViewController solved this for me